# Error: Load failed, save is disabled

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm completely new to ipython/ jupyter, I literally just typed in me first example and went to save it. I'm not getting the error above?

Error: Load failed, save is disabled

Also I don't know if it is related but I can't left click into cells? I have to right click and then press escape (very annoying).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Javascript developer console and read the error msg. 
In my case it looked like:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.min.js:12623 Object
main.min.js:12625 API request failed (404): No such file or directory: code/pcc/Prototype%%20Pattern.ipynb
main.min.js:26690 Error stack trace while loading notebook was:
main.min.js:26691 XhrError: No such file or directory: code/pcc/Prototype%%20Pattern.ipynb
    at wrap_ajax_error (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:12671:29)
    at Object.settings.error (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:12692:24)
    at l (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:89:24882)
    at Object.c.fireWith (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:89:25702)
    at k (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:91:5373)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/static/notebook/js/main.min.js?v=40e10638fcf65fc1c057bff31d165e9d:91:9152)
main.min.js:12030 Loaded extension: widgets/notebook/js/extension
```